# matza significance

Tags: passover, passover-seder-hagada, matzah

I would like to know the meaning of the three matzot and why only the middle one is broken.

Comment: And the Vilna Gaon's practice was only to use 2 matzas.  He felt it wasn't a problem to make HaMotzee on one-and-a-half matzas.

Answer (score 6):

From "[The Historical Haggada](http://levinejudaica.com/catalog/product_info.php?cPath=32_158_576_1027&products_id=11787&osCsid=4fe29649c6614b590a9d13b97ae230d8)," by [R' Nachman Cohen](http://www.pearlmancta.com/TorahLishmaInstitute.htm) (p. 14):

> Of the three *matzot* on the table, why is it that the middlte *matza* is the one which is broken? The *halakhic* answer is: On *Pesach* three *matzot* are required. One for *lechem o'ni* (poor man's bread) and two for *lechem mishna* (the two loaves required on each *Shabbat* and *Yom Tov*). Since it is customary to lay one's ten fingers on the *lechem mishna* [as a reminder that ten *mitzvot* are fulfilled in the process of producing and eating bread] these *matzot* must be placed on the top and bottom of the pile.

He also quotes "two of many" answers "on the level of *derush*. I'll leave it to others two write up their favorites from that category.

Answer (score 6):

There are many explanations, meanings and innuendos. Here are a few:

Avraham served the Angles-disguised-as-men three loaves when they arrived at his home. That was on Pesach.

We compare the Matzah to "poor man's bread" an a poor man always puts some away for later, hence the "break and hide" routine of the middle matzah. Plus, hiding a piece of Matzah alludes to the Torah's instruction "You shall guard the Matzos".

Three matzas represent the Patriarchs, Avraham, Yitzchak and Yaaakov. Avraham was the man of Chesed (kindness and benevolence), Yitzchak of Gevurah (stern discipline) and Yaakov of Tiferet (balance and Torah study). Yitzchak's harshness needs to be broken to allow people leeway in their approach to G-d.

Comment: I accept this reply above #256 given by ChabadRabbi. I mean the one which the three matzot represent the Patriarchs. At least until
another more adequate turns up. Unfortunately, I don't have one of my own.